# Chrome No Cache

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, jboss, cache-control

I am facing an issue with JBOSS and Chrome. Our applications use standard session management handling.

When the user keeps the page past the session timeout limit, then they click a link on a page, the application takes them back to the login page to re-login. That's is working as expected. The problem is when they user re-login and goes to the same page as before and click the same link, Chrome takes them back to the login page, even though they just logged in.

If we do clear cache manually on Chrome and then go back to the page, the link works fine. It seems as if Chrome cached the page with the information of this link to go to login instead of where it's supposed to go.

We added the following to the jsp pages but it did not work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

This works fine on IE by the way, it's only Chrome.

We found a way around it by adding in the spring controller class itself the following code:

```
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1);
```

But this is going to require to add this code to every controller class we have, and not all the apps we have use spring.

Is there a JBOSS server param that I can set to force no cache response, or maybe I can add this param as an attribute in the web.xml ?

I am trying to find a simple way to do this, instead of having to make changes in many places.

We're using Java with Spring (struts too) and HTML5 on JBOSS EAP 6.1

Thank you

Comment: append a random timestamp as a query parameter on every click. You will never get the same full url twice and it should just ignore the query parameter on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Java solution is to create a Filter class or Spring MVC interceptor to manage all requests/responses which are sent back to the browser which will set the headers into all responses.

For record, if you´re using a webserver to redirect the traffic to the application server you could also set those variables in there, Apache has some modules to manage it.